# Unterschied zwischen „Kommilitonen“ und „Klassenkameraden“

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Als Nicht-Muttersprachler habe ich die Vermutung, dass mehr Bedeutung hinter diesen beiden Wörtern steckt.

Wird eines häufiger mit bestimmten Altersgruppen oder Geschlecht benutzt? (Jungs/Mädchen)?

Dürfen diese Wörter verwendet werden, um Bezug auf Menschen in einem Kurs zu nehmen, wenn man älter als dreißig ist?

Comment: Note: "How does it sound"-like questions *can't be answered by any dictionary*, these questions can be answered exclusively by a living, and cooperative native speaker. I suggest leave open.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Es ist ganz einfach:

*Kommilitonen* sind Mitstudenten, *Klassenkameraden* sind Mitschüler.

Eine Unterscheidung nach Alter und Geschlecht gibt es nicht. Es kann 17-jährige Studenten an der Uni geben, die Kommilitonen haben, und 22-jährige an einem Abendgymnasium, die einander Klassenkameraden sind. Natürlich gibt es auch die weiblichen Formen *Kommilitonin* und *Klassenkameradin*.

Comment: Das errinnert mich an der Unterschied zwischen Student und Schüler danke.

Answer (score 4):

*Kommilitone* wird nur auf Universitäten (und ev. Fachhochschulen, keine Ahnung) verwendet, aber nicht in Schulen. Dort gibt es Klassen, was auf der Universität (im deutschsprachigen Raum) regelmäßig nicht der Fall ist.

Comment: Auch an Fachhochschulen bezeichnet man seine Mit-Studenten als Kommilitonen